# to open new page for successful registration in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I have code something like this

```
 router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
```

//saving to db if successful
       res.sendStatus(200);
});

on successful registration i want to open a new page!!!

Comment: go watch tutorials in YouTube (:

Comment: simply call `res.redirect('/some/route')` at the end of routine. nodejs is not clientside technology so it cannot open a new page, but You can open new page with clientside js code by doing `new Window()` in case when nodejs part respond with success.

Comment: @num8er your advice is appreciated !!! nodejs is of course not client side technology and my question is not about that. I didn't use ajax call. So how i can get response on my client side js file.

Comment: simply You can only redirect using `res.redirect` but You cannot open new page.

Comment: @num8er i hope you didn't understand my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want redirect page in your project, try this:

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    ...
    do something
    ...
    res.redirect('/foo/bar');
}
```